# UL is not centering when inside a div float:right

Tags: css

Please review the fiddle here for an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/TKJsc/1/

Basically i'm trying to make it so the `UL` is centered in it's parent `div`.

Each `li` has a `width`, and if i use `inline` it will not render with the width.  If i use `inline-block` then IE doesn't render it properly, but FF does.  How would i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 doesn't work quite right with inline-block due to a bug with some proprietary concept called `hasLayout`. If an item `!hasLayout`, it is considered inline.

To fix it in IE8, all that is necessary is to give it some property which will trigger `hasLayout == true`. The most simple way to do it is with the again ms-proprietary `zoom:1;`

For more details, check out this very in depth article: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline` instead of `float: left` on your `li` elements, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/TKJsc/

Comment: when i do that i lose all of the width and margins it seems like, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/TKJsc/1/  I did `inline-block`, but then i dont get the horizontal position in IE, it thinks its `block`

Answer (score 0):

Try display: inline-block instead of float: left.
This way you get the margins and padding, and the inline behaviour.

http://jsfiddle.net/juanojeda/asfjK/

Comment: that is the closest that works, but `inline-block` doesn't render properly in IE8, how do i get it to work in IE8 also?